# how to get data which contains $ ` € and some Round Bullets using web service in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, web-services, nsxmlparser

I am making a Business IOS application for  iPhone. I am calling  web service, it's sends data in JSON Format.the response  contains character Like **$** and  **'** and **€** and some **Round Bullets**.

when I am calling the web service  while parsing data come their but before these characters data is present but after these charcters data is not their .But if i replace character( $ and  ` and € and some Round Bullets) in web service my data in Xcode comes successfully.

I don't know why at the time of parsing or encoding in xcode if these character are their i  get partial  data from my web webservice.And i want data with these charters without Replacing in web web service.

this is all method in .m file used for response from web service

```
  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
    {
        [self.webResponseData  setLength:0];

    }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {

       [self.webResponseData  appendData:data];
    }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"%@" , error);
        NSLog(@"Some error in your Connection. Please try again.");

    }

    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"Received %lu Bytes", (unsigned long)[webResponseData length]);

        NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:
                            [webResponseData mutableBytes] length:[webResponseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"theXML%@",theXML);
           //now parsing the xml
        NSData *myData = [theXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSLog(@"myData%@",myData);

        NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:myData];
        NSLog(@"xmlParser%@",xmlParser);

        //setting delegate of XML parser to self
        xmlParser.delegate = self;
        BOOL parsingResult;
        // Run the parser
             @try
              {
                  parsingResult = [xmlParser parse];
                  NSLog(@"parsing result = %hhd",parsingResult);
              }
            @catch(NSException* exception)
             {
                      UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Server Error" message:[exception reason]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                     [alert show];
                    return;
            }
    }

    -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:
    (NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
    {
        currentElement = elementName;
        NSLog(@"currentElement%@",currentElement);

    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
    {

    data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"string data come after parsing  = %@",string);
        arrjson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"GetElucHeaderDetailsResult"])
        {
            currentElement=string

    }
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
        {
              NSLog(@"Parsing Done");

        }
```

**my response from web service  is below  :-**

```
[{"GeoLevelCode":"AJ","GeoLevel":"S","ButterFlyType":"1","YearMonth":"0217","FinYear":"2017","Carrier":"KL","HeaderEluc":"NTR  Further improvement of 11 Mln EUR, evenly split € UK and IE Sales Cost under control and in line ","DetailEluc":"NTR  Further improvement of 11 Mln EUR, split between UK and IE for UK coming from Jan actuals vs PFC, IE shows improvement in rest of the year  Access in general is ok and base load being established up, continued access remains key, yield slightly better than anticipated; Net Sales cost   Relative small increase in Net Sales Cost, with increase in NTR keeping NSCR at same level as pfc; Net Station Cost  very slight increase in Net Cost per Seat due to lowered seatsmovement with higher lounge costs (mix and usage), and slight increase in various Other Costs; FTE  Slight decrease in KL Sales due to delayed recruitment of sales staff in UK, year effect  02 fte ","Details2Eluc":" vs BGT: Increase of NTR by 115 Mln Euro (bud rox), while Net Sales Cost decrease slightly  FTE change from AF to KL due to vacancies being filled in on KLcontract Station Cost impacted by less seats with more movements and handling price increase at LHR Cost target settings from budget released, costs levels are cleaned for this effect","AddedOn":"3/1/20179:52:50PM","AddedBy":"KLM71111@caas","LastUpdatedOn":"","LastUpdatedBy":""}]
```

string data come after parsing  from foundCharacters method is:- in this data after euro sign data is not come:-

```
[{"GeoLevelCode":"AJ","GeoLevel":"S","ButterFlyType":"1","YearMonth":"0217","FinYear":"2017","Carrier":"KL","HeaderEluc":"NTR  Further improvement of 11 Mln EUR, evenly split  

   2017-04-05 11:00:15.892 Butterfly2BE[942:67462] array  DATA = (null)
```

**see this line from response data:-**

"HeaderEluc":"NTR  Further improvement of 11 Mln EUR, evenly split € UK and IE Sales

Comment: please provide the response(coming from ur web service) ... then only its easy to resolve ur issue.

Comment: sir i has been edit my question with code and response from API.